# Extract specific words from the file

Tags: python, text, read-text

I am analyzing some text files and I want to extract a specific word every time that the word is found in the file.

Imagine that I have 'Sports' in the file then I want to extract the Word 'SPORTS' based on a list.

I've the following code:

```
content = ['Sports', 'Nature', 'Football']
path = filename
with open(path) as auto:
    for line in auto:
        if any(x.lower() in line.lower() for x in content):
            print(line)
```

My text file has this content:

```
Sports TV is the home of football videos. 
Complex game to follow.
home of football
```

With my code I print all the lines with 'Sports' and 'Football':

```
Sports TV is the home of football videos. 

home of football
```

But I want to see the following result:

```
Sports
football
```

How can I print only the word that I have on List instead of all the line?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Are you checking if the text contains the word? Are you counting amount of times the words were found in text? Are you looking at grammar (as in starts with capital letter, plural, etc.)?

Comment: I will export a lot of analysis for a file and one of the columns is the word found on the file that matches with my list

Comment: and how will you manage multiple found words? Like 1st sentence in your case where there are football and sports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.txt:

```
Sports TV is the home of football videos. 
Complex game to follow.
home of football
```

**Hence**:

```
content = ['Sports', 'Nature', 'Football']
path = 'list.txt'

with open(path) as auto:
    print([[x.lower() for x in content if x.lower() in line.lower()] for line in auto])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[['sports', 'football'], [], ['football']]
```

**Since**:

> line 1 had `sports` and `football`
>
> line 2 had no matching elements from content list
>
> line 3 had `football`

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the entire line at the moment

try:

```
content = ['Sports', 'Nature', 'Football']
path = filename
with open(path) as auto:
    for line in auto:
        for x in content:
            if x.lower() in line.lower():
                print(x)
```

Comment: modified to not print a list with values but only the content value